# use same random array for each sort

Tags: java, sorting, random

I'm trying to make it so i generate a random array but implement just that one same array(in the random order) with different sorts. I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);}

    System.out.println("\nBefore Bubble Sort: ");
    for (int element : array)
        System.out.print(element + "  "); 

    bubbleSort(array);


    System.out.println("After Bubble Sort: "); 
    for (int element : array)
        System.out.print(element + "  ");
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("\nBefore Insertion Sort: ");
    for (int element : array)
        System.out.print(element + "  "); 

    insertionSort(array);


    System.out.println("After Insertion Sort: "); 
    for (int element : array)
        System.out.print(element + "  ");
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

With corresponding code for the sorts (I will post them if necessary). Its output is:

```
Array Before Bubble Sort: 
2 64 27 1 81 60 72 6 9 82
Array After Bubble Sort: 
1 2 6 9 27 60 64 72 81 82 

Array Before Insertion Sort: 
1 2 6 9 27 60 64 72 81 82 
Array After Insertion Sort: 
1 2 6 9 27 60 64 72 81 82
```

I want this array `2 64 27 1 81 60 72 6 9 82` to be in the before insertion line as well. The sorted array from bubble sort is just being put in the insertion sort so it's not doing anything. I think I need to make a method for the random array and call that with each sort? How would I do that? Or any other solution I'd appreciate. I will edit with more information if needed.

Comment: Use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to copy your array into a 'fixture', and copy that fixture back before each sort execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone or copy the array before each sort and pass the clone to the sort routine. You can use `array.clone()` or `Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length)` to make the copy.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int[] array = new int[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);}

   System.out.println("\nBefore Bubble Sort: ");
    for (int element : array)
      System.out.print(element + "  "); 

   int[] sorted = array.clone();
   bubbleSort(sorted);


   System.out.println("After Bubble Sort: "); 
    for (int element : sorted)
      System.out.print(element + "  ");
      System.out.println("\n");

   System.out.println("\nBefore Insertion Sort: ");
    for (int element : array)
        System.out.print(element + "  "); 

    sorted = array.clone();
    insertionSort(sorted);


    System.out.println("After Insertion Sort: "); 
    for (int element : sorted)
        System.out.print(element + "  ");
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you this works. However it seems other than bubble sort, when i try to count comparisons and swaps, its counted as 0 swaps for insertion sort. So it's "magically" getting sorted without swapping and just printing out the sorted list. Do you know why?

Comment: @vee - I suspect you aren't re-cloning the array. See my updated answer, where I replaced the `// etc.` with explicit code.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a **copy** of initial array in order to maintain the same data as original.